# Incompatible types error when calling java webservice

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I have a Netbeans webservice that returns an object(Matrix) from the Jama package, but when I call the webservice from client I am getting a compile error of "incompatible types". Below the code of the webservice and the client.

My webservice:

```
package Protocol4_Service;

@WebService(serviceName = "Cloud1")
public class Cloud1 {

private Jama.Matrix xPrimeMatrix;

public Cloud1(){ }

 @WebMethod(operationName = "saveXPrime")
 public void saveXPrime(Jama.Matrix xp){
   xPrimeMatrix = xp;
 }

}
```

My client:

```
package MyTest;

public class Test {

@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="http://mypc:8080/ServiceCloud/Cloud1?wsdl")
static Cloud1_Service serviceCloud1;

private Cloud1 portCloud1;
private Jama.Matrix xprime;

public Test(){
    serviceCloud1 = new Cloud1_Service();
    portCloud1 = serviceCloud1.getCloud1Port();


    //COMPILE ERROR: incompatible types: Jama.Matrix cannot be converted to Protocol4_Service.Matrix
    portCloud1.saveXPrime(getXPrime()); 

 }

 private Jama.Matrix getXPrime(){
    xprime = x.inverse();
    return xprime;
 }

}
```

I am using the same package in both sides. I read that the classes generated by the tool are not the same as the original ones, but I don't know how to make the types compatible. If you can point some code it could be the best.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you clean and rebuild the Project?

Comment: I did but that does not solve the problem. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039468/netbeans-webservice-client-stubs-incompatible-type but it is not clear to me how they solve the issue